# Overlay issue in i18n AEM6.0

Tags: aem

We have some sites such as:

```
/apps/site1
        |----i18n
               |---data
               |---keys
               |---languages
               |---translator

/apps/site2
        |----i18n
               |---data
               |---keys
               |---languages
               |---translator
```

Now when we hit the site, we can see the call `libs/cq/i18n/dict.xx-xx.json`. Ideally that call should be either from `/apps` or `/etc`. How can I achieve this?

OOTB servlet :

```
@Component
@Service({Servlet.class})
@Properties({@Property(
    name = "service.description",
    value = {"ResourceBundle Renderer Servlet"}
), @Property(
    name = "sling.servlet.paths",
    value = {"/libs/cq/i18n/dict"}
)})
public class ResourceBundleExportServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, as of aem 6.3 (and earlier versions) that path was hard-coded pretty much everywhere it was used. to use a custom path you will have to-

1. Register custom servlet at /apps/cq/i18n/dict.xx-xx.json (or path of your choice) to return i18n values.
2. Change AEM ootb code that uses the hardcoded path to use your custom path.

Comment: By the way, I am using 6.0. But still in that servlet  `ResourceBundleExportServlet` which returns json. path is hardcoded. So shall i need to go customizing OOTB functionality of I18N? Updated question with OOTB servlet.

Comment: I think that is what you will need to do. We had this use case sometime back and wanted to use custom dictionaries for each site, ended up abandoning the approach. seemed too much of hassle.